# Can Functions that are threaded access member variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Hi all to start off with:

Using QT Version 5.4.1

Using Gdal/Ogr

Coding in C++

So I'm doing quite a heavy function, which downloads, parses and outputs some data from a WFS. And I'm now threading this function so it stops locking the GUI thread.

So this is what I'm doing QtConcurrent::run(this,&myClass::heavyfunction); My question is, can this threaded function access member variables? that have been set before it runs? Or will I have to pass that member variable into the function as a parameter.

Comment: It can access member variables (non-UI controls...) in reading. If you need to update them then you also need some sort of synchronization mechanism. Of course this is a _general_ answer, if you access a non-const method (or even a const one with access to a mutable member) then you'll need synchronization again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the documentation for [QTConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html):

> QtConcurrent::run() also accepts pointers to member functions. The
>   first argument must be either a const reference or a pointer to an
>   instance of the class. Passing by const reference is useful when
>   calling const member functions; passing by pointer is useful for
>   calling non-const member functions that modify the instance.

it seems that you should be able to access the members of the class. So the short answer is yes, just make sure you do not pass as in as a const.

However, aside from grabbing a thread off the thread pool, I'd suggest you do some locking on the resource as otherwise you might find your self in a bit of a pickle.

I suggest you use one of the thread sync objects.  QMutex, QReadWriteLock, QSemaphore, and QWaitCondition

Here is where I suggest you start (QreadWriteLock/Qmutex might be the simplest for you to use, but have a read and make up your own mind).

1. [Thread Synchronization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html)
2. [Threads and qObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)

(still editing the long answer, will post in update shortly).

Comment: Ah okay great that makes sense. Because I have 3 heavy functions ahah! This is going to be a fun afternoon doing this thanks man!

Comment: @JakeWade pleasure :)

Comment: Okay just did a quick check with my project, so yeah QTConcurrent::run does access and parse the member variables and quite cleanly! But I got to make sure I can manage the data race though!